# After deleting/changing a specific CSS part ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS occurs

Tags: php, html, css, apache, firefox

A few days back I added a overlaying gradient effect to one of my pages. I wrote it directly between two `<style>` tags for testing into my `index.php`. Now I wanted to copy it into my `.css` file but whenever I delete or change the following part from my file the site is not accessible anymore because of an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

This ist the part causing the problem (notice: the css works find. I can't delete it anymore from the source file without causing errors):

```
gradient {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  right:17px; bottom:25px; left:17px;
  height:125px; /* adjust it to your needs */
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,alotofcodehere);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 70%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(70%,rgba(255,255,255,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 70%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 70%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 70%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
}​
```

What I've done so far:

- deleted every browser data, even manually for several times now
- allowed third party cookies
- private mode
- read a lot of different threads about the error
- restarted my PC, apache, nearly everything

But nothing works and now I'm very suspicious what causes this weird problem. I tried to access the site from another machine with Chrome and Edge. Same issue. When I copy back the CSS part shown above, everything works fine.
The console shows the following:

[image]

Could there be a -maybe- caching problem with apache? I'm very confused at the moment. Never though a CSS definition can affect a site in that way.

Does anyone have any idea or keywords for me? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I've made my code not using sessions and cookies anymore but this didn't do the trick. It's the CSS part that still causes the problem whereas I have no idea how.

**UPDATE:**
The `header(...)` caused the problem. I have to write it inside the curly brackets:

```
if(isset($_POST['RequestType']) && isset($_POST['OperatingSystem'])  ) {
    saveRequest();
} else if(isset($_POST['RequestToDelete'])) {
    deleteRequest();
} else if(isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    login();
}
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: Please post the code rather than a picture of it so we can paste it into an IDE for testing.

Comment: @vascowhite silly me. updated my post.

Comment: Can you post an expanded picture of your developer tools, it should indicate where your re-direct source is.

Comment: @DanBelden uploaded the expanded window of one of the messages.

Comment: This indicates the re-direct is in PHP, not in any CSS/JS. You'll need to identify where in your code it issues a 302 re-direct. Without PHP code we can't help. PS: This is not likely to be CSS in origin bug as it's triggered server side

Comment: @DanBelden Okay thank you very much. I was very confused about this cut-and-past-back thing of the CSS that seemed to cause the problem. I'll try to figure out where the problem could be in my php code and maybe pastebin it if I can't find a solution.

Comment: @DanBelden well that was fast, I've got it (snippet in OP). The `header` outside of the curly brackets caused the problem. May I ask you -now that you know the problem- if you have any idea how this was affected by the CSS or why this code in generall caused this loop?

Comment: Ha. Glad you found the instigator. However, without the full file PHP code - there is little I can do to highlight why the CSS had an impact on your file.

Comment: PS: if that PHP code is in the index.php file it will cause an infinite re-direct as it is executed on every page request and tells the browser to re-direct to itself